# Check Why Sympy in Python so Slow to Calculate Symbolic Integration for Sphere Surface Area

Tags: python, sympy

is SymPy the only reliable package in Python to do symbolic integration? I try SymPy for Julia, and it can compute faster. Please check whether this code is efficient, or something wrong in it. Thanks all..

It is just to prove that the surface of area of a sphere is the one and only 4 pi times r square.

```
import sympy as sy

x = sy.Symbol("x")
r = sy.Symbol("r")

def f(x):
    return sy.sqrt(r**2 - x**2)

def fd(x):
    return sy.simplify(sy.diff(f(x), x))

def f2(x):
    return sy.sqrt((1 + (fd(x)**2)))

def vx(x):
    return 2*sy.pi*(f(x)*sy.sqrt(1 + (fd(x) ** 2)))
  
vxi = sy.Integral(vx(x), (x, -r, r))
vxf = vxi.simplify().doit()
```

It's been an hour after I run `vxi.simplify().doit()` and it has not even finish yet

[image: 1]

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of SymPy. I can't reproduce the problem you reported.

Comment: My SymPy is 1.10.1 with Python 3.9.13

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question,

I have realized that I have found the solution by adding an assumption:

the same as in Julia.. since it is the same SymPy:

```
r = sy.Symbol("r", nonnegative=True)
```